# How did the program pass the linker?

Tags: c++

Here is the program `link_function.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
    public:
        Base() {
            init();     // first condition
         //   log();    // second condition
        }

        virtual ~Base() {}

        virtual void log() = 0;
    private:
        void init() {
            log();
        }
};

class Derived: public Base {
    virtual void log() {}
};

int main() {
    Derived d;
    return 0;
}
```

**First Condition**

`make link_function` passed.  `./link_function` produced error as below.

```
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception
Aborted (core dumped)
```

How did `init()` function passed the linker without produced a `undefined to reference log()` error??

**Second Condition**

When I comment `int()` and just call log(), It produced an `linker error`.

`undefined reference to 'Base::log()'`.

What's the **difference** between them?

Comment: It is a strong implementation detail.  But there isn't any way for the linker to reliably discover that the v-table contains an uninitialized entry.  Most of all because C++ classes have two v-tables.  The real one doesn't get put into place until the constructor finished executing.

Comment: I guess the linker may find the Derived class's `log()` implementation though the v-tables in **First Condition**. But Why it do not find one in **Second Condition**. It know it's a bad pratice to call virtual function in a Base Construtor. I'm just curious about the detail. Can you recommend me some book about these? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Derived classes are built from the base class up. During the constructor of Base, the constructor of Derived has not yet been executed. Therefore the vtable is not yet complete.

Calling virtual functions (even non-pure ones) in a constructor is naughty. It implies an incorrect class design.

Here's why it's a bad idea:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base {
    public:
        Base() {
            init();
         //   log();
        }

        virtual void log() { cout << "stange outcome 1" << endl; }
    private:
        void init() {
            log();
        }
};

class Derived: public Base {
    public:
    virtual void log() { cout << "stange outcome 2" << endl;}

    Derived() 
    : Base() 
    { 
        log();
    }
};

int main() {
    Derived d;
    d.log();
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
Compiling the source code....
$g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o demo -lm -pthread -lgmpxx -lgmp -lreadline 2>&1

Executing the program....
$demo 
stange outcome 1
stange outcome 2
stange outcome 2
```

Explanation of why:

When we create an object of class Derived, the program does the following:

1. Allocate memory big enough for a Derived
2. Set the vtable pointer of the object to point to a vtable of a Base
3. execute Base::Base() [ calls to log() will call Base::log() ]
4. Set the vtable pointer of the object to point to a vtable of a Dervied
5. execute Derived::Derived() [ calls to log() will call Dervied::log() ]
6. object is now fully constructed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I know calling a virtual function in a Base Constructor is really a bad practice. However, The condition one and condition two which are so similar produced difference result. I'm just curious about these.

Comment: During the constructor, Base is completely unaware that there is anything derived from it. It's vtable is the vtable of a Base.
When Derived's constructor is called, it modifies the vtable (actually probably replaces it with a new one) of Base.

Comment: Therefore, after finishing compiler phase, are the vtable of Base the same in **two conditions**? As they both pass the compiler phase while condition two failed in linker phase.

Answer (score 0):

Your `log` function is virtual, so linker doesn't worry about it. Linker doesn't care about virtual functions because their address is known only at run-time.

The issue with your code is that you call virtual function from `Base` constructor. But at the time when `Base` constructor is called, `Derived` isn't constructed yet, so `log` function is kind of undefined.

Each object of `Derived` class contains "sub-object" of `Base` class which is constructed before object itself (That is, `Base` constructor is called prior to `Derived`). When `Base` constructor executes it doesn't know virtual table of `Derived` class, so it can't resolve address for `log` to call. Thus it considers it to be a pure virtual function and aborts execution.

Comment: You said `Linker doesn't care about virtual functions because their address is known only at run-time.` But in condition two, the linker **complains**.

Comment: It looks like compiler recognizes `log` in the constructor as non-virtual method (since it can't call virtual ones anyway) and tries to call `log` directly. It doesn't complain about `init` because 1) it could be called outside the constructor, 2) complete analysis of source code is computationally expensive (and limit to some extent, see halting theorem). But that's my opinion.